# Is it possible to save from ongoing damage, if submerged in the source of the damage every turn?

Tags: dnd-4e, damage, saving-throw

Specifically: in H2: thunderspire Labyrinth in the Hall of the Crimson Whip, there are pools of poisonous blood. The damage states: "Any creature that is not a demon and enters or starts its turn in a blood pool takes 1d10 poison damage, and ongoing 5 poison damage and a -2 penalty to all defenses against the attacks from demons (Save ends both).

So if you are still submerged in the blood/poison can you make the saving throw to end the effects? It seems that being in the stuff means that it is constantly being reactivated so saving vs one instance of it doens't help because it just hits you again.

Am I wrong thinking you would need to find a platform outside of the poison to make the saving throw and remove the negatives?

Thanks!

Comment: For what it’s worth, I believe you’re correct that the effect is restarted every round a character “starts its turn in a blood pool,” but I don’t have enough 4e knowledge to be sure so only a comment, not an answer. Hopefully someone will be around to confirm or refute this authoritatively pretty soon.

Comment: 4e is really all about the RAW and nothing about reality. From the wording, it looks like you get your normal save each turn, and the affects would start again on your next turn.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and great question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes**

If players remain in the pool of poisonous blood the will take the 1d10 + 5 ongoing damage every turn they remain in the pool. The ongoing damage will not stack (same source, same amount), but they will get a save against the ongoing damage every turn, at the end of their turn. This is because a player can end their turn in the pool, save vs the poison and then be moved out of the pool by some kind of forced movement or an ally PC's action.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the answer, I appreciate it. That bit about the forced movement didn't cross my mind before. Additionally, if a character was a Warden and used Font of Life to save at the beginning of his/her turn... I suppose it could avoid the ongoing effect, but still take the 1d10 damage.

Comment: @mengaroth yes, depending on level (though I assumed this was heroic tier based on that damage amount) almost any character can have access to save at start of turn features depending upon paragon path.

Comment: Font of Life (Warden, PHB2) should also be considered -- they get to save against one effect at the _start_ of their turn, before they take the ongoing damage from the previous turn. It would still reapply, of course.